# Interface with implementation without abstract class?

Tags: c#, .net, abstract-class, interface-implementation

I am writing a library and I want to have an interface

```
public interface ISkeleton
{
    IEnumerable<IBone> Bones { get; }
    void Attach(IBone bone);
    void Detach(IBone bone);
}
```

The Attach() and Detach() implementation actually should be the same for every ISkeleton. Thus, it could essentially be:

```
public abstract class Skeleton
{
    public IEnumerable<IBone> Bones { get { return _mBones; } }

    public List<IBone> _mBones = new List<IBone>();

    public void Attach(IBone bone)
    {
         bone.Transformation.ToLocal(this);
         _mBones.add();
    }

    public void Detach(IBone bone)
    {
        bone.Transformation.ToWorld(this);
         _mBones.Remove(bone);
    }
}
```

But C# doesn't allow multiple inheritance. So among various issues, users have to remember to inherit from Skeleton every time they want to implement Skeleton.

I could use extension methods

```
public static class Skeleton
{   
    public static void Attach(this ISkeleton skeleton, IBone bone)
    {
         bone.Transformation.ToLocal(skeleton);
         skeleton.Bones.add(bone);
    }

    public static void Detach(this ISkeleton skeleton, IBone bone)
    {
        bone.Transformation.ToWorld(this);
         skeleton.Bones.Remove(bone);
    }
}
```

But then I need to have

```
public interface ISkeleton
{   
    ICollection<IBone> Bones { get; }
}
```

Which I do not want, because it is not covariant and users can bypass the Attach() and Detach() methods.

Question: Must I really use an abstract Skeleton class or are there any or tricks and methods?

Comment: Off-topic: I would recommend to name it `SkeletonBase` but that's a subjective decision.

Comment: why must it be `IEnumerable`?

Comment: If your Sceleton implementation will be same, so first question why you need interface? I would use abstract SceletonBase

Comment: Why not make `Skeleton`/`SkeletonBase` implement `ISkeleton`, or just get rid of `ISkeleton` altogether?

Comment: "users have to remember to inherit from Skeleton" - same could be said of ISkeleton, could it not?

Comment: in both ways users need to remember inherit something. :)

Comment: @DanielA.White because I do not want users to modify the collection without using through Attach and Detach.

Comment: Then don't make the collection public. Don't expose it.

Comment: @Oded Sorry, I wasn't clear: I am actually saying I am stuck choosing between ISkeleton and SkeletonBase.

Comment: Jake - if an abstraction is not useful, get rid of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make bones a special type that implements `IEnumerable<T>`. That way it doesn't violate the single responsibility principle.

```
public interface ISkeleton
{
    AttachableEnumerable<IBone> Bones { get; }
}

public class AttachableEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    // implementation needed.
    void Attach(T item);
    void Detach(T item);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly. So embarassed I failed to see this pattern.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to expose the `Attach` and `Detach` methods in your interface, there is always a way to bypass your intended implementations, as all objects implementing the interface can implement them on their own style.

You can let the abstract class `Skeleton` implement `ISkeleton` and all classes which are Skeletons do inherit from `Skeleton`, thus they implement `ISkeleton` as well.

```
public interface ISkeleton { ... }

public abstract class Skeleton : ISkeleton { ... } // implement attach and detach

public class SampleSkeleton : Skeleton { ... }
```

This way you can use your `SampleSkeleton` as `ISkeleton`, you don't have to implement these functions as long as you inherit from `Skeleton` and marking the methods as `sealed` does not allow overriding them (as long as they are instance methods).

On a side node: Do name your abstract class with `Base` at the end or mark the base class somehow else (but this is surely up to you).

Comment: In which case, `ISkeleton` is not needed.

Comment: @Oded you're right, of course. But if the abstract class `Skeleton` (or any class which inherits from it) provides other public methods (to implement other interfaces as well) one should use interfaces to control the access.

Comment: So... with regards to my actual question stated in the last of the my post, you are saying abstract class is the way to go?

Comment: @Jake no and yes :) It absolutely depends on the greater scope of your project, in terms of your software architecture. Use interfaces to hide the implementation, but not if a single class implements the whole interface with no additional functionality (see Oded's comments).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wrap `ISkeleton` behaviour, you could always make it a composite object instead of inheriting the behaviour:

```
public class Body : ISkeleton
{
    private SkeletonImpl _skeleton = new SkeletonImpl;

    public IEnumerable<IBone> Bones { get { return _skeleton.Bones; } }

    public void Attach(IBone bone)
    {
        _skeleton.Attach(bone);
    }

    public void Detach(IBone bone)
    {
       _skeleton.Detach(bone);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you just have to use sealed methods on abstract Skeleton class?
This way they can't be overriden.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645769(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper class which implements the 'Attach' and 'Detach' methods and inject this Functionality to your Interface.